# Alert the user if value exists in database after user leaves textbox

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a textbox on form. What I would like is when a user leaves textbox, that he/she would be informed that value he/she entered exists. Values are stored in SQL Server database. 
I have found something similar [here](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/2297/how-to-check-whether-username-exists-in-database-without-refreshing-pa).

It works ok, but it causes PostBack.

Comment: you should use ajax and that request should then talk to database to check any existing data in the table. Based on the results handle your user interface.

Comment: So you don't want to use ASP.NET ajax? You could use a webmethod. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/byxd99hx(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: @Yoda+5uperdan: he has used ajax but he don't want a postback. Ajax also uses a postback even if not the whole page is refreshed on clientside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I did. 
First I added onblur on aspx textbox with function call. Something like:

```
 <asp:textbox id="id" onblur="MyFunction()" <br/>
```

In JavaScript I added function:

```
function MyFunction() {
    var id= document.getElementById('TextBoxID').value;
    if (parseInt(id)) {
        PageMethods.FunctionInCodeBehind(klid,Success,Failure);
    }
function Success(response) {
    alert ('Success');
}
function Failure (response) {
    alert('Failure');
}
```

In code behind I created function:

```
<System.Web.Services.WebMethod()> _
Public Shared Function FunctionInCodeBehind(ByVal bo As Integer) As Integer
  Dim something as Integer         
  ' Do stuff so I could return something
  Return something

End Function
```

It works.